# DataGridView selectedRow Property not get Data if i double click Row?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, gridview, datagridview

i click double dataGridView's any row. Not get Data clicked row data:

```
 
  private void gwStudies_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            GoruntuyuAc();
        }

private void GoruntuyuAc()
        {
            olduid = "";
            DataRowView ro = (gwStudies.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as DataRowView);
            string uid = "";
            uid = ro["StudyInstanceUid"].ToString();
            string tarih = "";
            DateTime t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(ro["StudyDate"]);
            //........
           //............
        }
```

**Error Data on (gwStudies.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as DataRowView);**

IMAGE:[image]

Answer (score 1):

here u have to pass row index and column index in GoruntuyuAc(int row,int col) function.
like GoruntuyuAc(e.RowIndex,e.ColumnIndex);

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure, but I think the selection on happens after the double click event.

Comment: @programmerist: Use the `SelectionChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe `SelectionChanged` event or try something like this:

```
  private void gwStudies_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            olduid = "";
            DataRowView ro = (gwStudies.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as DataRowView);
            string uid = "";
            uid = ro["StudyInstanceUid"].ToString();
            string tarih = "";
            DateTime t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(ro["StudyDate"]);
            //........
           //............
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only to give you a best practice, In order to be sure about the clicked DataGridView, you should cast the sender as follows

```
void transactionsGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView senderDataGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
        YourBoundModelClass row = 
            (senderDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as YourBoundModelClass);
        //...
    }
```

this is strongly typed too.